# Sending an email with CFMAIL inside of a CFSCRIPT

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I wrote an application at work that uses a few CFC's- I'm having some errors but I want to actually mail the errors out because the application is live and they are happening rarely.

I can't stop what's currently running to troubleshoot.

Does anyone have any experience/can point me towards doing `cfmail` inside of a cfc/cfscript? More specifically, inside of a try/catch within cfscript.

We're running ColdFusion 9 which doesn't support `<cfmail>` inside of `<cfscript>`.

Comment: I use cfmail inside the onError function of some Application.cfc's and I'm running CF9. I use the tag, but I'm not sure what your problem is.

Comment: @DanBracuk his cfc is script and he can't use cfmail in script on CF9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `mail` CFC is built in to CF9 and above. You can use it in cfscript and it shouldn't matter where you implement it - within a try/catch block should be fine in `onError`.

Adobe has an example of the usage in their documentation for CF9:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0693d5dae123bcd28f6d-7ff9.html

Comment: Thanks, Sean. This is exactly what I needed. Makes me feel stupid but it had been a long day. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Write a new cfc with a function to send an email and then include that within the `try`/`catch`. Something like below will work

sendMail.cfc (missing a lot of things, but this is the structure)

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
  <cffunction name="sendEmail">
    <cfargument name="errorMessage">
    <cfmail>
      <cfdump var="#arguments.errorMessage#">
    </cfmail>
  </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

try {
  //code here
} catch (any e) {
  var sendEmail = new sendMail();
  sendEmail.sendEmail(e);
}
```